# tableView.setScrollEnabled is No, DidSelectRowAtIndex not responding

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

If tableView.scrollEnabled = NO, then didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not responding to first touch, but only to the second select row. Do you have any idea why??

Please help.

Comment: Show your code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have not implemented

```
didDeselectRowAtIndexPath
```

rather than implementing

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```